# Absolute/Conditional Convergence or Divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{1/n}}{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I'd just like to verify that my solution is right. This is for the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{1/n}}{n^3}\text{.}$$
Note
$$\left|\dfrac{\left[\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}e^{1/(n+1)}}{(n+1)^3}\right]}{\left[\dfrac{(-1)^{n}e^{1/n}}{n^3}\right]}\right| = \left|-e^{1/(n+1)}e^{-1/n}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{3}\right| \to 1 \cdot 0 \cdot 1^{3} = 0$$
as $n \to \infty$. Hence by the ratio test, the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126, no, that's not correct.

Comment: Well, it is correct apart from a typo, undoubtedly $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}\not\to 0$ was intended.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What was intended was $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not correct. When one applies the Ratio Test, the limit is $1$. so the Ratio Test is *inconclusive*.

For a correct proof, note that the absolute value of the $n$-th term is $\le \frac{e}{n^3}$, so we have absolute convergence by Comparison.

Comment: If the limit is actually $1$, can you tell me where I messed up in my limit calculation?

Comment: We have $e^{1/(n+1)}\to 1$ and $e^{1/n}\to 1$, and hence $e^{-1/n}\to 1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Quick question: I'm looking at the back of this textbook for the answer (Stewart), and it says that the series is absolutely convergent. How would one show this under a time crunch if the ratio test doesn't work? (This is for the Math GRE.)

Comment: I gave a partial answer to that already, by saying that the absolute value is $\le \frac{e}{n^3}$. It is a standard fact that $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ converges ($p$-series, $p\gt 1$).

Comment: Ah, that works. Thank you!

Comment: I would not even try the Ratio Test, seeing that nice $n^3$ in the denominator, and the harmless $e^{1/n}$ in the numerator. Not doing the Ratio Test is a real time saver!

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to see that this converges which is applicable in a wide variety of cases is to consider how quickly the summand shrinks; in particular, using Big-O notation, we see that $e^{1/n}$ is $O(1)$, since it converges towards a limit as $n$ grows large. The denominator is $O(n^3)$, so the ratio, which is the summand, is clearly $O(n^{-3})$, so convergence of this series is the same as the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-3}$, which is convergent.